# Trusted email: Digital signature with Gmail (IE)

Tags: gmail, internet-explorer, digital-signature

[There](http://www.instantssl.com/ssl-certificate-products/free-email-certificate.html) are places in the internet, where you can get a free digital signature for email.

How can I use it with Gmail and Internet Explorer?

Comment: Internet Explorer might not be the best choice to do that since it does not support extensions.

Comment: Related: [Digitally sign Gmail emails with S/MIME](http://superuser.com/questions/406289/digitally-sign-gmail-emails-with-s-mime).

Answer (score 4):

I you use Firefox, you can use Firegpg ( http://getfiregpg.org)

Comment: FireGPG has been discontinued on June 7, 2010.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments in this [Gmail support forum thread](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=5cd94f01fad7b573&hl=en), it looks like you may either have to use a desktop mail client (such as Outlook or Thunderbird), or use Firefox instead with extensions to allow certificates to be added to Gmail.

Comment: [Gmail S/MIME](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gmail-smime/) extension doesn't work anymore.